# Unable to match parent the custom dialog's width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am have created a custom dialog and defined the width as `match_parent`. But when I ran the application, it appears not even wrapping the content as most of the content is getting clipped. I tried some of the solutions but getting the same result, I have no idea what am I doing wrong:

**dialog_messages.xml**

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_msg_sm"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/normal"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorDanger"
                android:padding="@dimen/normal_2x"
                android:text="Send Message"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGrey" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/normal_2x"
                android:text="Tap a message to send"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_sm1" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/normal_2x" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGrey" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/normal_4x"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/colorDanger" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

and the setup class

**MessageDialog.kt**

```
    class MessageDialog(
        private val activity: Activity,
        private val onMessageClickListener: MessageClickListener
    ) : Dialog(activity) {

        private val messageList = arrayListOf<String>(
            "Can't locate you. Send instructions",
            "Heavy Traffic. I'll be late 10 minutes",
            "Just turning around the block",
            "Taxi arrived",
            "I am coming to your location",
            "I am arriving in 5 minutes",
            "Ok"
        )
        private lateinit var listView: ListView
        private lateinit var btnCancel: Button;

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_messages)

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList)
            listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
            listView.adapter = adapter
            listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                onMessageClickListener.onMessageClick(messageList.get(position))
                dismiss()
            }

            btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is the result:
[image: The end result]
I have tried some other answers already provided here, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Dialog object and do this in the show() part.

```
    val dialog = MessageDialog(activity, messageClickListener)

    val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.window!!.attributes)
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

    dialog.show()
    val window = dialog.window
    window!!.attributes = lp
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i was using afollestad material dialog library, and it had default margin. I overrided that margin on my dimens.xml file

```
<dimen name="md_dialog_horizontal_margin">8dp</dimen>
```

Here 8dp means, dialog both from left and right margin will be `16 dp` so if you want margin to be 16dp type it as 8dp, divided by two :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this inside your Dialog class:

```
 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
}
```

Have fun coding!
I also got the answer from this [post](https://medium.com/@lovejjfg/android-dialog-layout-match-parent-not-work-789cd23bc0de), thanks a bunch.